# jsp input text id only accept strings

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to do a project using jsp and now i'm stuck. I need to get the value of a input text using js.

But i have a problem my jsp variable is a integer and inputText only accept string. So my question there are anyway to convert it?

```
<h:inputText id="#{foo.id}"  />
```

I already treid using id= <%=String.valueOf(foo.id) %> but i receive:

> According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [id]
>   does not accept any expressions

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `f:convertNumber` with `integerOnly` attribute. See also: [JSF Core Tag Reference f:convertNumber](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertNumber.html).

Comment: Ah, id... ummh.